# GSAP ScrollTrigger with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, gsap

I'm trying to use `ScrollTrigger` with Next.js:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
```

I got this error: [image]

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### UMD option

You can either load the **UMD** version (located under the `dist/` subdirectory).

```js
import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
```

---

#### ESM option

**OR** use the default **ESM** format and transpile `gsap` library in Next.js.

To do so, you'll first need to install `next-transpile-modules`.

```sh
$ npm install next-transpile-modules
```

Then some extra setup in your `next.config.js` file is required.

```js
// next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["gsap"]);

module.exports = withTM({});
```

You'll be then able to import it the way you currently are.

```js
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work ->

`import { gsap } from "gsap/dist/gsap";` 
`import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";`

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34615660)